# Nearest neighbor image resizing wrong using scipy and PIL

Tags: python, scipy, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I'm trying to take a small image and make a large ("pixelated") version of it using Python. I've tried using the nearest neighbor resizing methods in both `scipy` and `PIL.Image` and both output the same wrong result. Here's an example when trying to upsample an image by a factor of 3:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imresize
from PIL import Image

img = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], dtype=np.uint8)
img_nn_scipy = imresize(img, (9, 9), interp='nearest')
img_nn_pil   = np.array(Image.fromarray(img).resize((9, 9), Image.NEAREST))

print img_nn_scipy
print img_nn_pil
```

Both print statements output the same result:

```
[[1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3]
 [1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3]
 [1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3]
 [4 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6]
 [4 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6]
 [4 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6]
 [4 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6]
 [7 7 7 8 8 8 8 9 9]
 [7 7 7 8 8 8 8 9 9]]
```

I expected that each number in the original image would now be replaced by a 3x3 block all containing the same value. Instead, the blocks have varying sizes, and only the `1` block is 3x3.

Is there a reason for this? Is there a way to reasonably solve this in Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the latest [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/) instead of PIL.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: from PIL import Image
   ...: 

In [2]: img = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], dtype=np.uint8)

In [3]: img_nn_pil   = np.array(Image.fromarray(img).resize((9, 9), Image.NEAREST))

In [4]: print img_nn_pil
[[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
 [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
 [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6]
 [4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6]
 [4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6]
 [7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9]
 [7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9]
 [7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9]]
```

This was just a bug that [was fixed](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/2022).

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Also, apparently the reason the scipy implementation gave the same result is that it uses PIL. Using Pillow fixes scipy as well.